# Lightswitch 2013 linked SQL Database Project disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

OK, after lots of searching I've boiled this down to an extremely simple repro and am very confused. I have VS 2013, all updates, etc.

1. Create new HTML Lightswitch app, creates 3 projects.
2. Add new database project to solution
3. Go to Lightswitch properties (of "common" project)

Result: SQL Database Project drop down is disabled and set to .

Expected: My new db project to be listed for me to link.

Comment: Did you find why that combobox is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You must create at least one table in the Intrinsic Database before you can choose an SQL Database Project to link to your LightSwitch Project. That is, right-click "Data Sources" and choose "Add Table".

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2013/07/03/intrinsic-database-management-with-database-projects-chris-rummel.aspx:

> The last step to using the database project is to let LightSwitch know
>   about it.  Open the LightSwitch project properties and select your
>   database project.
>
> [image]
>
> **Note that you won’t be able to select a database project if you don’t
>   have any intrinsic tables, so if you’re trying this out in a new
>   project you’ll have to create a table first.**